# How to apply ng-style on ng-click dynamically to selected item without using ng-class in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to apply ng-style on ng-click dynamically without using ng-class in angular? something like changing color for selected active menu only. something like this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtQNQXOLggs1bsYKNJvx?p=preview) but with ng-style. Below is my code which is toggle function. Can anyone solve this by changing the code or use your own example to change color or font-size for active item when clicked and rest of the items to default state.

```
<div ng-style="x.selected && {'color':'white','font-weight':'bold'}"  
    ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in myData" ></div>


var app = angular.module('anApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2452"
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "value": "2458"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2457"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "2459"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "2460"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "3458"
  }
];

$scope.select = function(x){
  x.selected = !x.selected;
}
})



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
<div ng-style="x.selected && {'color':'red','font-weight':'bold'}"  
    ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in data" >
      {{x.value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to use it for dynamic content like ng-repeat data which comes from xml. Then i will have only one div. <div ng-style="" ng-click="select(x)" ng-repeat="x in data" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.menuItems = ['Home', 'Contact', 'About', 'Other'];
  $scope.activeMenu = $scope.menuItems[0];

  $scope.setActive = function(menuItem) {
    $scope.activeMenu = menuItem
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="account-item" ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>
    <div class="account-heading" ng-style="activeMenu === item && {'background' :'red' }">
      <h4 class="account-title">
        <a href="#/Messages" ng-click="setActive(item)"> {{ item }}</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using $index as below example with plunker below,

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z977olOlajTNZENbqx7D?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data" ng-click="setSelected($index)" ng-style="$index === selectedId && {'background' :'red' }">
    {{x.value}}
</div>
```